# Se me presento el siguiente error en Docker Desktop Windows 10: ¨error internal load metadata for docker.io¨

Tags: linux, windows, docker, contenedores

Estaba generando una nueva imagen de Docker a partir de un Dockerfile, cuando se me presento:

```
error internal load metadata for docker.io/library/
```

Traté de utilizar otro `Dockerfile` con otras configuraciones, pero me siguió apareciendo el mismo error, decidí desinstalar y volver a instalar `Docker Desktop` en `Windows 10` y aún así el error sigue sucediendo. No entiendo qué sucede, ya que antes de este error podía generar múltiples imágenes con diferentes `dockerfile`.
Este es uno de los `Dockerfiles` que trate de ejecutar:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get install -y vsftpd 

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 21 

EXPOSE 3306  



CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda, ya que llevo días tratando de resolver este problema.

Muchas gracias.